# Unable to display an image in secondviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new to iPhone development. I have two views named pickerviewcontroller and secondviewcontroller which have different xib files. I choose a picture through the UIImagePickerController interface from the Photo Library, and I was trying to display the chosen image in the second view. pickerController is my first view controller.

pickerController.h file

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "SecondViewController.h"

    @interface pickerControllerViewController :  UIViewController<UIActionSheetDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
     IBOutlet UIButton *selectpic;
  UIImageView *imageView;
    }
    @property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageView;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *selectpic;
    -(IBAction)getpic:(id)sender;
    //-(void)goNext: (UIImagePickerController *)picker;
    @end
```

pickerController.m fie

```
#import "pickerControllerViewController.h"

@implementation pickerControllerViewController
@synthesize imageView,selectpic;
-(IBAction)getpic:(id)sender
{
 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{

 imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
 [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 SecondViewController *secview = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 [secview setImage:imageView];

}
```

SecondVIewController.h file

```
@interface SecondViewController :UIViewController{
 IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView2;

}
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image;
@end
```

SecondVIewController.m file

```
@implementation SecondViewController
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image{
 imageView2 = image;
}
```

It is not showing any error. I am not able to display the image in the secondview.

Comment: Your types are all messed up... There is a difference between a UIImage and a UIImage view. I am wondering why this doesn't crash all the time...

Comment: ya i agree.Later i changed uiimageview to uiimage and tried itstill am not getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In firstviewcontroller.m

```
<#import "pickerExampleViewController.h"

@implementation pickerExampleViewController
@synthesize selectPic;
-(IBAction)getpic:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.editing  = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

#pragma mark imagePickerController delegate methods

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker
       didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image 
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo  
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    Second *secview = [[Second alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second" bundle:nil];
    secview.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [secview.imgView setImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:secview.view];
    [secview release];
}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}<
```

In second.m you have to write

```
<#import "Second.h"

@implementation Second
@synthesize imgView;

-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    [imgView setImage:img];    
}
-(IBAction)back
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [imgView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
<
```

Answer (score -1):

Create A NSData Variable in pickerControlle class
and Store The Image Data in NSData

Then Pass The NSData To Next Class

Comment: i have taken NSData type and stored the image in it and i passed the data to setImage method in second view controller.Still am not getting .